# How can I convert BdsTabelle.Current("TABLE_NAME") from vb.net to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

Hi guys I have the following code in vb.net (framework 4.5)

```
 Private Sub CaricaComboTabelle()
    Dim i As Integer
    BdsTabelle.Filter = "TABLE_TYPE='TABLE'"
    cmbTabelle.Items.Clear()
    For i = 0 To BdsTabelle.Count - 1
        cmbTabelle.Items.Add(BdsTabelle.Current("TABLE_NAME"))
        cmbTabelle.Items.Add(BdsTabelle.Current("TABLE_NAME"))
        BdsTabelle.MoveNext()
    Next
    cmbTabelle.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub
```

How can I convert the code in c#?
I have tried this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bdsTabelle.Filter = "TABLE_TYPE='TABLE'";
        cmbTabelle.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < bdsTabelle.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            cmbTabelle.Items.Add(bdsTabelle.IndexOf("TABLE_NAME"));
            BdsTabelle.Current["TABLE_NAME"];
            bdsTabelle.MoveNext();
        }
        cmbTabelle.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

But dosen't work because here Current is a property `Readonly`

My goal is load `BdsTabelle.Current("TABELE_NAME")`(that is a `BindingSource` in cmbTabelle that is a `ComboBox`

Comment: Maybe provide a little more information about exactly what you are attempting to do.

Comment: What is that you want to do

Comment: What object type is cmbTabelle? BdsTabelle?

Comment: cmbTabelle is a combobox BdsTabelle is a BindingSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'for' loop ending condition is incorrect - the C# equivalent is:

```
for (i = 0; i < BdsTabelle.Count; i++)
```

or

```
for (i = 0; i <= BdsTabelle.Count - 1; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ ---> 95 % right.
You have to paste "all" (Importend code like:Imports System.Data.SqlClient and class.... ) of your code to translate it

Comment: Sorry but dosen't work because the converter dosen't translate Current correctly(in c# is readonly)